# How to make sure a Div with vertical scrollable capability , can only scroll inside a particular div?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Let's say I have the following HTML and code:

```
<div class="divOne"></div>

<div class="divTwo">
    <div id="blue_square" style="top: 310px;">Blue</div>
</div>

<div class="divThree"></div>
```

```
#blue_square {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 9;
  width: 370px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px transparent;
}
```

```
$("#blue_square").css("top", $(window).height() / 2 - 80)
```

I have this blue_square div that has a `position fixed` and can be scrolled along with divTwo content block.
But the problem I am seeing is that the blue_square div can also be seen while I scroll even divOne and divThree content block.

Is there a way to prevent `blue_square` from showing up on `divOne` and `diveThree` while I am scrolling their content ? The ``blue_square `should only on appear on` divTwo `block.

Comment: divOne and divThree would be sections? What if you use them with position: relative and z-index (more than blue_square element)?

Comment: @Kloves  I just used divOne and DivThree as an example. There could be divfour, Divfive, DivSix, etc, on the page.  My question is how can I limit blueBox only to divTwo.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution to that is `position: sticky` (https://caniuse.com/css-sticky - It's compatible with modern browsers).

An example using your idea:

```css
#blue_square {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  width: 370px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 6px transparent;
  top: calc(50% - 10px);
}

div[class^="div"] {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="divOne"></div>

<div class="divTwo">
    <div id="blue_square">Blue</div>
</div>

<div class="divThree"></div>

<div class="divFour"></div>

<div class="divFive"></div>
```